How to add a WMS layer to QGIS using PyQGIS with custom authentication headers
I’m working on adding a WMS layer to QGIS using PyQGIS, and while it works perfectly without authentication, I’m having trouble when custom authentication headers are required.
Here are the scenarios I have tested:

Adding WMS Layer Without Authentication
I successfully added a WMS layer without authentication using the following code:
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject

wms_url = (
    "contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&"
    "format=image/png&layers=BlueMarble-200401&styles=&url=https://worldwind25.arc.nasa.gov/wms"
)

wms_layer = QgsRasterLayer(wms_url, "Blue Marble 2004-01", "wms")

if wms_layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(wms_layer)
    print("Blue Marble WMS layer added to QGIS.")
else:
    print("Failed to add the Blue Marble WMS layer to QGIS.")




This works perfectly and displays the layer in QGIS.

Requesting a WMS Image with Authentication Using requests
I can successfully retrieve a single image from the WMS using custom headers with the requests library:
import requests

wms_url = "some_url"

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
    'Accept': 'image/png'
}

response = requests.get(wms_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("wms_layer.png", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
    print("WMS image saved successfully as 'wms_layer.png'")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve WMS layer. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)




This approach also works fine for fetching individual images.
However, I need to add a WMS layer directly to QGIS with custom headers (e.g., API subscription key and bearer token) similar to the first example. I’ve tried setting up a custom QgsNetworkAccessManager to include headers, but I’m not sure how to integrate it into the PyQGIS workflow to load the WMS layer.
Questions:

Is there a way to integrate custom headers directly when adding WMS layers in PyQGIS?
Can I use QNetworkRequest or QgsNetworkAccessManager to add these headers when adding WMS layers?

I’m using QGIS 3.28. Any guidance or working examples on this?

One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

I used this solution as a basis, which uses QgsDataSourceUri to create the wms connection url. QgsDataSourceUri has a setHttpHeaders method, which you can use to pass your authentication token.
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer


uri_config = dict(
    layers="rgb_2018",
    crs="EPSG:4326",
    format="image/png",
    url="https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_sentinel2_de",
    contextualWMSLegend='1',
    styles=''
    
)

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
for key, val in uri_config.items():
    uri.setParam(key, val)

headers = QgsHttpHeaders({'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
# headers = QgsHttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'f"Bearer {token}'})
uri.setHttpHeaders(headers)

layer = QgsRasterLayer(bytes(uri.encodedUri()).decode(), 'rgb_2018', "wms")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

